# How add extra to parent activity in TaskStackBuilder

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I need to add data to parent activity in `TaskStackBuilder`.
In notification i have next code:

```
val taskStackBuilder = android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.create(context)

val intentMain = Intent(context, getMainActivityClassReference())
intentMain.putExtra("TEST KEY", "TEST VALUE")

taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(getMainActivityClassReference())
taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intentMain)

val intentChat = Intent(context, ChatActivity::class.java)
intentChat.putExtra(ChatActivity.CHAT_UID_KEY, data.chatUid)

taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intentChat)

val pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

In second intent (with ChatActivity) i have correct workflow with extras - `intent.extras.getString(ChatActivity.CHAT_UID_KEY)` return correct value. But when i back press and check in main activity data (`intent.extras.getString("TEST KEY")`) return always null.

How with `TaskStackBuilder` correctly add data in intent where he is not top?

Comment: Can you show how you reading data in getMainActivityClassReference() class?

Comment: @Vishu sure! `intent.extras.getString("TEST KEY")`